# Formatting a MySQL Query result

Tags: mysql

I've currently got a table as follows,

```
Column      Type
time        datetime             
ticket      int(20)              
agentid     int(20)              
ExitStatus  varchar(50)      
Queue       varchar(50)
```

I want to write a query which will break this down by week, providing a column with a count for each ExitStatus. So far I have this,

```
SELECT ExitStatus,COUNT(ExitStatus) AS ExitStatusCount, DAY(time) AS TimePeriod 
FROM `table` 
GROUP BY TimePeriod, ExitStatus
```

Output:

```
ExitStatus ExitStatusCount TimePeriod
NoAgentID                1          4 
Success                  3          4
NoAgentID                1          5
Success                  5          5
```

I want to change this so it returns results in this format:

```
week | COUNT(NoAgentID) | COUNT(Success) |
```

Ideally, I'd like the columns to be dynamic as other ExitStatus values may be possible.

This information will be formatted and presented to end user in a table on a page. Can this be done in SQL or should I reformat it in PHP?

Comment: So far, i'm thinking I should use GROUP_CONCAT(ExitStatus) and then use PHP to go through the comma delimited fields. Is this the way to go?

Comment: Is something like this what you're looking for?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736010/how-to-group-by-week-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "general" solution to your problem (called **cross tabulation**) that can be achieved with a single query. There are four possible solutions:

- Hardcode all possible `ExitStatus`'es in your query and keep it updated as you see the need for more and more of them. For example:

```
SELECT
    Day(Time) AS TimePeriod,
    SUM(IF(ExitStatus = 'NoAgentID', 1, 0)) AS NoAgentID,
    SUM(IF(ExitStatus = 'Success', 1, 0)) AS Success
    -- #TODO: Add others here when/if needed
FROM table
WHERE ...
GROUP BY TimePeriod
```

- Do a first query to get all possible `ExitStatus`'es and then create your final query from your high-level programming language based on those results.
- Use a special module for cross tabulation on your high-level programming language. For Perl, you have the [SQLCrossTab module](http://search.cpan.org/~gmax/DBIx-SQLCrosstab-1.17/SQLCrosstab.pm) but I couldn't find one for PHP
- Add another layer to your application by using OLAP (multi-dimensional views of your data) like [Pentaho](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/) and then querying that layer instead of your original data

[You can read a lot more about these solutions and an overall discussion of the subject](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2003/12/04/crosstabs.html)

Comment: This looks like the ticket. Had thought about doing your first suggestion after reading Jacks suggestion. Will go ahead with that.

Comment: yup, my first solution is exactly like all others (I also corrected the bug, thanks for pointing it out). I also added other ways to approach the problem too

Comment: True but the part I needed was the suggestion to do an initial query to get unique ExitStatus and build a new query from that in PHP

Answer (score 0):

This is one way; you can use `SUM()` to count the number of items a particular condition is true. At the end you just group by the time as per normal.

```
SELECT DAY(time) AS TimePeriod, 
  SUM('NoAgentID' = exitStatus) AS NoAgentID, 
  SUM('Success' = exitStatus) AS Success, ...
FROM `table` 
GROUP BY TimePeriod
```

Output:

```
4 1 3
5 1 5
```

The columns here are not dynamic though, which means you have to add conditions as you go along.

Comment: Hmm...perhaps I can do one query to ask for unique ExitStatus and then build your suggested query dynamically from that. I'd hoped for a single query solution but this could work [Edit]: I see Toote just suggested that below]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT week(time) AS week,
        SUM(ExitStatus = 'NoAgentID') AS 'COUNT(NoAgentID)',
        SUM(ExitStatus = 'Success') AS 'COUNT(Success)'
FROM `table`
GROUP BY week
```

I'm making some guesses about how ExitStatus column works.  Also, there are many ways of interpretting "week", such as week of year, of month, or quarter, ...  You will need to put the appropriate function there.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this won't work with `COUNT()`, considering that `SELECT COUNT(0)` yields one.

Comment: @Jack I think your are right. Editing to SUM, following your example :)