# SQL query for various time periods

Tags: mysql

[image]

I have a table that contains Following entries:

```
completed_time||   BOOK_CNT
*********************************************
2013-07-23    | 2
2013-07-22    | 1
2013-07-19    | 3
2013-07 16    |5
2013-07-12    |4
2013-07-11    |2
2013-07-02    |9
2013-06-30    |5
```

Now, I want to use above entries for data analysis.

Lets say DAYS_FROM, DAYS_TO and PERIOD are three variables.

I need to fire following sort of queries:

"**Total book from DAYS_FROM to DAYS_TO in interval of PERIOD.**"

**DAYS_FROM** is a date in format YYYY-MM-DD

,**DAYS_TO** is a date in format YYYY-MM-DD

**PERIOD** is {1W,2W,1M,2M,1Y}
 where W,M,Y represents WEEK,MONTH and YEAR.

Example: The queries DAYS_FROM=2013-07-23 , DAYS_TO=2013-07-03 and PERIOD=1W should return:

```
ith week - total
1 -        3
2-         8
3-         6 
4-         14
```

**Explanation**:

```
1-3 means (The total book from 2013-07-21(sun) to 2013-07-23(tue) is 3 )
2-8 means (The total book from 2013-07-14(sun) to 2013-07-21(sun) is 8 )
3-16 means (The total book from 2013-07-07(sun) to 2013-07-14(sun) is 6 )
4-14 means (The total book from 2013-07-03(wed) to 2013-07-07(sun) is 14 )
```

*Please refer the calendar image for better understanding*.

How to fire such query?

What I tried?

```
 SELECT DAY(completed_time), COUNT(total) AS Total
  FROM my_tab
 WHERE completed_time BETWEEN '2013-07-23' - INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND '2013-07-03'
 GROUP BY DAY(completed_time);
```

The above queries subtracted 7 days from 2013-07-23 and thus considered  **2013-07-16 to  2013-07-23** as **first week**,  **2013-07-09 to  2013-07-16** as **second week** and so  on.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yes Its mysql.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to group by week in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736010/how-to-group-by-week-in-mysql)

Comment: It would be better to store the date as timestamp. So you can calculate better with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple starting point would be something like below, of course you may want to adjust the `ith` value to suit your needs;

```sql
SET @period='1M';

SELECT CASE WHEN @period='1Y' THEN YEAR(completed_time) 
            WHEN @period='1M' THEN YEAR(completed_time)*100+MONTH(completed_time)
            WHEN @period='2M' THEN FLOOR((YEAR(completed_time)*100+MONTH(completed_time))/2)*2
            WHEN @period='1W' THEN YEARWEEK(completed_time)
            WHEN @period='2W' THEN FLOOR(YEARWEEK(completed_time)/2)*2
       END ith,
       SUM(BOOK_CNT) Total
FROM my_tab
GROUP BY ith
ORDER BY ith DESC;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0dbe/4).

Comment: Thanks a lot!! That's exactly what I wanted. :)