# Group by week in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

Table structure is,

```
Table name: btq_user

name, email, kall, state_id, datain
```

Now i want to count number records which has kall = 1 or state_id in( 51, 20, 46) by weekly.
i need the results only by weekly (Mon - Sun) no matter if year changes. lets say for example 31-12-2012 is Monday and 6-1-2013 is Sunday so result should include that as a week. no matter if year changes it should count only with weeks.

This is what i tried but not working.

```
SELECT 
count( if( A.state_id = 51 or A.state_id = 20 or A.state_id = 46, A.state_id,
null  ) ) AS state_total, count( if( A.kall =1, A.kall, null ) ) AS appointment, 
CONCAT( WEEK( A.datain) , " - 
", YEAR( A.datain ) ) AS week
FROM btq_user A
GROUP BY week
ORDER BY A.datain ASC
```

also is there any possibility to display weeks ( 31-12-2012 - 6-1-2013 ) with results ?

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: Take a look at this question and answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736010/how-to-group-by-week-in-mysql

Comment: Do you have a index on column datain? And how many records are in the table right now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two steps to this:

One, you need a week-truncate operation -- that will take your `DATETIME` item and give back midnight on the preceding Sunday (if your business rule says that the week begins on Sunday).

That becomes a suitable GROUP BY item. The WEEK() / YEAR() hack isn't suitable for this. It really makes a mess in the last/first week of each year.

In my experience, this exxpression will do the week-truncate trick for you, Sunday - Saturday,

```
  FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(TIMESTAMP) -MOD(TO_DAYS(TIMESTAMP) -1, 7))
```

To get Monday - Sunday weeks, use this expression.

```
  FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(TIMESTAMP) -MOD(TO_DAYS(TIMESTAMP) -2, 7))
```

So you can do this.

```
  SELECT COUNT(whatever), SUM(whatelse),
         FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(event_time) -MOD(TO_DAYS(event_time) -1, 7)) as WEEKSTART,
    FROM TABLE
   GROUP BY FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(event_time) -MOD(TO_DAYS(event_time) -1, 7))
```

[How to group by week in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736010/how-to-group-by-week-in-mysql)

Second, you need to add six days to that truncated date, so you can display the last day of each week along with the first day.

This is a good way to do that, with a nested query

```
SELECT whats, elses, weekstart, weekstart + INTERVAL 6 DAY AS weekend
  FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(whatever) AS whats, SUM(whatelse) AS elses,
         FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(event_time) -MOD(TO_DAYS(event_time) -1, 7)) AS weekstart,
    FROM TABLE
   GROUP BY FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(event_time) -MOD(TO_DAYS(event_time) -1, 7))
  ) AS summary
ORDER BY weekstart
```

Doing lots of this? I suggest you create a stored `TRUNC_WEEK` function.

Comment: can you give me an example ? i need week totals even for 31-12-2012 To 6-1-2013 (Mon To Sun). thanks