# ordering different database rows into groups based on weeks

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting, time

I tried to Google this, but all I could find was how to sort alphabetically which I already know. Basically I would like to sort my different rows and print them out based on their date value.

This is printing out a competition schedule. I want to organize it by weeks and print it out so all of the first weeks games are printed together and in a different div the 2nd weeks games etc etc...

I don't want to use a `WHERE()` clause with a certain date because I have multiple leagues with multiple start dates and the dates will definitely not be the same. I feel like it would be very sluggish to search through every possible date.

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: You need to show us the query you're trying.

Comment: Can't use `WHERE`, then try `GROUP BY` and/or `ORDER BY`

Comment: sort by date, then by name

Comment: search this forum for: How to group by week in MySQL? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736010/how-to-group-by-week-in-mysql

Comment: @Fred-ii- , `GROUP BY`?  Really? I don't see any requirement for an aggregate in this question.

Comment: @OllieJones Notice the `or` in there? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is conceptually straightforward, if a little messy in syntax.

You need an expression that will turn any `DATE` into the first day of the week it contains, and then you need to `ORDER BY` that expression.

Here's the expression, given that your weeks begin on Sundays.

```
FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(event_date) -MOD(TO_DAYS(event_date) -1, 7))
```

So a query roughly like this will do the trick for you.

```
SELECT FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(event_date) -MOD(TO_DAYS(event_date) -1, 7)) AS week_begin,
       *
  FROM competition
 ORDER BY FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(event_date) -MOD(TO_DAYS(event_date) -1, 7)),
       team, whatever
```

This isn't nearly debugged; I don't know your column or table names.

This is written up in some detail here. http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/sql-reporting-time-intervals/