# Get last months data divided in weeks in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, php-carbon

Fellow coders,

I'm trying to get the data from last month divided in weeks from the database, I have heard about Carbon but I have no idea on how implement carbon in my actual data.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

I currently have

```
$currentDate = Carbon::now()->subWeek();
$agoDate = $currentDate->subDays($currentDate->dayOfWeek)->subWeek();
```

Which does return the useful date info. But I would love to see how it's executed with some dummy data

Comment: `GROUP BY CONCAT(WEEK(your_field), YEAR(your_field))`? Why do you need Carbon?

Comment: @IvankaTodorova Its for an hour registration system. For instance I've put in some dummy values for last week. What I have to do now is to create a dropdown menu in which multiple weeks are displayed. Might a user click on 24 - 4 - 2017 / 30 - 4 - 2017. then I need to retrieve the values from last week and display them on the page

Comment: I mean, isn't it better to use Carbon, and then to use the variables containing the Carbon data in my regular queries from Eloquent?

Comment: Or I might just be stupid

Comment: Carbon is for dates when you work with PHP, if you want to query data from your database, use sql.

Comment: I know... But I need to get data for every last week (maximum a month ago). Don't I need to use a Carbon function for that? Because I am really really inexperienced.. I would love some help if that's possible

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736010/how-to-group-by-week-in-mysql

Comment: Thanks for the link, i'll try to use raw sql in my Laravel app

Comment: Use can use `->groupBy(DB::raw('YOUR QUERY HERE'))`.

Comment: But even if I get the query to work. How will I be able to pass that data in Ajax so that when a value is selected in the dropdown, the correct values will be displayed