# MySQL: Grouping by date ranges

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

Say we have a table of `Products` with the columns `id, title, status, expires_at, created_at`.

I can get the values for single week by specifying all the parameters:

```
SELECT
    count(id)
FROM 
    products
WHERE
    status = 'APPROVED' AND
    expires_at >= '2018-09-10 09:00:00' AND
    created_at <= '2018-09-10 09:00:00' AND
    deleted_at IS NULL;
```

How could we run a query that groups the products by weeks of the year **1-52** -- WHERE each week shows Products that were not expired: `created_at <= week-end AND expires_at <= week-end` or *active*:

```
Active_Products | Week_Of_Year 
----------------|---------------
274             | 2018-01
----------------|---------------
1011            | 2018-02
----------------|---------------
180             | 2018-03
----------------|---------------
990             | 2018-04
----------------|---------------
765             | 2018-05
```

I have updated this question with an SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4830b/4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to group by week in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736010/how-to-group-by-week-in-mysql)

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result

Comment: Its not a duplicate if you take time to read the full specs of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query by calculating week start date and end date

```
select week(expires_at),count(id) as active_products
from product
where expires_at>SUBDATE(expires_at, weekday(expires_at)) and expires_at<DATE(expires_at + INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY(expires_at)) DAY)
group by week(expires_at)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the logic you want for the active products in a given week is more like `*created_at* >= week-start AND expires_at < week-end`.

If you have products created during all weeks, then you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select week_of_year,
       (select count(*)
        from products t2
        where yearweek(t2.created_at) >= w.week_of_year and
              yearweek(t2.expires_at) < w.week_of_year
       ) as num_actives
from (select distinct yearweek(created_at) as week_of_year
      from products
     ) w;
```

Comment: Ah I think this is really really close. Although its hard to understand what all the different table names are? where does the original `Products` table fit into that query?

Comment: @AndrewMcLagan . . . `t` is shorthand that I use for a generic table name.  Now that you've specified the table, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Not able to get this query working. I have created an SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4830b/4

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `YEARWEEK(date)` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek) to show the week number in a reada readable way **including the year** (yyyymm).

```
SELECT 
count(id) as active_products, YEARWEEK(expires_at)
FROM products
GROUP BY YEARWEEK(expires_at)
```

Using `WEEK()` will not make difference between years in the same week.