# How to group date between two past date in one column MYSQL

Tags: mysql, date

I have this Query

```
SELECT
DATE_ADD(table1.date, INTERVAL -7 DAY) AS date7,
DATE_ADD(table1.date, INTERVAL -14 DAY) AS date14,
DATE_ADD(table1.date, INTERVAL -21 DAY) AS date21,
table1.hotel AS hotel,
table1.customer AS Customer,
table1.date AS Date,
table1.sell AS Sells,
table2.adr AS ADR,
table2.revpar AS RevPAR,
table3.name_hotel AS Hotel_name,
FROM `table1`
INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.hotel=table3.hotel
INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.hotel=table2.hotel
AND table1.date_occ=table2.date_occ
```

I would like to get a column "weeks" where **Date** in between **Date** and **date7** then "last week", **Date** between **date7** and **date14** then "-2 week" and **Date** between in **date14** and **date21** then "-3week". Because I need to group in "weeks" to calculate sells last 7 days, 14 days and 21 days according current date

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to group by week in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736010/how-to-group-by-week-in-mysql)

Comment: In mysql you have several function for date year() week() ,,month()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
table1.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()
table1.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
table1.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 21 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub