# How to sum column during week of the last record?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I assume recording date of a user's the last activity as 13.04.2019 . I want to sum all records in the week belonging the last record.

---

ex:

created_at = 13.04.2019, activity = 3

created_at = 11.04.2019, activity = 3

created_at = 01.04.2019, activity = 3

//the above 3 records is not same week. I need last week to sum activites so the result of sum will be 6

---

How could I do this with Carbon or others

```
$sum_last_week = Model::where('user_id',$user->id)->orderby('id','desc')->sum('activity')
....
```

Comment: Last week total row or just one?

Comment: @TalhaF.  Total row

Comment: why not just to group by week https://stackoverflow.com/a/11759589/3256489 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First retrieve the last active date,

```
$model = Model::where('user_id', $user->id)->orderby('created_at',desc)->first();
```

Then, generate target range depending on above result

```
$testDate=$model->created_at;
$from = $testDate->startOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d H:i');
$to = $testDate->endOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

Last, retrieve sum

```
$result =Model::whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])->sum('activity');
```

Comment: created_at is a date column, so you don't need to ->format(), you can directly pass the Carbon instances.

Answer (score 1):

The `whereBetween` method verifies that a column's value is between two values.

```php
$from = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-7 days'));  
$to = date('Y-m-d');
$last_week = Model::whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])->get();
```